# App icon is not visible/missing

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

I am learning xamarin to build a mobile app but i don't have any idea of Xamarin and mobile apps. I have opened a blank mobile app and there is "Hello world" for sample and edited some text but my app icon is not visible or may be i don't know to make it visible

Comment: which application ? is it a forms application? which platforms are you running? if iOS set in asset catalogue if android set in manifest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Application Icon :

Navigate to `AndroidManifest.xml` and set

```
android:icon="@drawable/[icon_name_as_in_drawable]"
```

under `<application>` tag

---

Try this sample : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gZ3LiMukGdQVRMcnhNZURqR3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I did but still not working. On release it s opening directly to app but I want some thing like when we click to any icon then it should open

Comment: @Dharmesh : After release, you can see your app automatically starting. If you exit from application you can see your application with an icon and a name among all other applications in the emulator or device.

Comment: yes,app automatically starting but on existing from application i can't see icon

Comment: @Dharmesh : Checck this sample : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gZ3LiMukGdQVRMcnhNZURqR3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How did you fix this Dharmesh?

Comment: FYI: the link is dead

Answer (score 3):

By default, your activity will not show up in Android's application launcher screen. This is because there will likely be many activities in your application, and you don't want an icon for every one. To specify which one should be launchable from the application launcher, use the MainLauncher property. For example:

```
[Activity (Label="Awesome Demo App", MainLauncher=true)] 
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```

This example produces the following xml fragment:

```
<activity android:label="Awesome Demo App" 
          android:name="md5a7a3c803e481ad8926683588c7e9031b.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: This answer helped me - Have a look in the decorator above the class in MainActivity.cs, the icon is being set there, for the launch activity.

Answer (score 1):

First check your drawable folder if ic_launcher.png is there or not. If it is there then open `AndroidManifest.xml` then

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" //application icon
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: tried but not working i might be possible that i am making mistake somewhere else can u explain from beginning please

Comment: Check out my recent ans..Register your main_activity like the given format in manifest...Hope it will work for u

Answer (score 0):

I followed this instructions relating to Xamarin / Visual Studio development
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#dotfuscator][1]

But its not too clear on referencing the icon. It didn't work at first but it worked after making this small change to MainActivity.cs under the Android application. Removed Icon reference from Activity.

```
    //, Icon = "@mipmap/icon"
[Activity(Label = "TwiceBy", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
```